# Bitwise OR - unexpected results in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

We recently had an issue with a generated SQLite query where we unintendedly used the bitwise OR:

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE ((nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1))
```

We fixed this issue by using the `OR` operator.

But the query above had some unintended behavior which I don't understand:

1. Why is this even working? (e.g. in Microsoft SQL Server this is clearly a syntax error)
2. Why are the results all rows with `nullableId = -1`?
3. In short, what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `nullableId IS NULL` then the conditions evaluate:
`nullableId IS NULL` to 1
`nullableId = -1` to `NULL` (because any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL`)
So this expression:

```
(nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1)
```

is evaluated to `NULL`, and since t is **not** `TRUE` these rows are not returned.
But when `nullableId = -1` then the expression is evaluated to:

```
0 | 1 = 1
```

so all the rows with `nullableId = -1` are returned. 
You can see this behavior in a table like this:

```
create table demo(nullableId int);
insert into demo(nullableId) values
(1), (null), (-1), (2);
```

The query:

```
SELECT *, 
  (nullableId IS NULL), 
  (nullableId = -1),
  (nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1)
FROM demo
```

returns:

```
| nullableId | (nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1) | (nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1) |
| ---------- | -------------------- | ----------------- | ---------------------------------------- |
| 1          | 0                    | 0                 | 0                                        |
| null       | 1                    | null              | null                                     |
| -1         | 0                    | 1                 | 1                                        |
| 2          | 0                    | 0                 | 0                                        |
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have a built-in boolean data type.  Instead, the values are stored a integers, with "1" (or not-zero) for true and "0" for false, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Because `0 | 1` = `1`, this happens to work as you want.

Comment: The expression: `((nullableId IS NULL) | (nullableId = -1))` **never** evaluates to: `1 | 1`.